# How to get a JAR executable file for an applet with no main class?

Tags: java, applet, executable-jar

The export options of eclipse require me to specify a main class.  However in a java applet there is no main class.  How do we get around this?

Comment: 1) Specifying a `main-class` in an applet will not hurt it.  Just point it to the applet class and be done with it.  2) Why are you developing an applet rather than a frame based project?

Comment: I have only learnt how to work with the GUI elements of a Java applet.  I just wanted to get a small program made for a friend.

Comment: Since you have not really begun to deploy yet, I'd say your learning is about 3% complete.  Deploying an applet has been known to drive people mad.  Put everything from the applet in a frame and deploy that using JWS and I believe it will be faster than deploying an applet successfully.

Comment: @AndrewThompson said it best. Doing anything AT ALL with an applet besides looking at it by yourself will drive you mad. I think I've already gone mad myself. It is unreasonably difficult to do anything with an Applet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible, since applets are meant to be run in the context of a browser, and executables are meant to be run independently.

Answer (score 0):

In the export dialog box, 
You should uncheck .classpath and .project since they are Eclipse project definitions. Click Next

Depending on the JDK, your code may produce warning and errors which wasn't present on older JDKs.  I'd advise correcting them before building JAR files, but if you want to ignore them, then click Next.

This final dialog usually throws users off.   In that if you try to Browse the Main class field nothing is shown (there's no class to select).  In fact, for Applets, you do not need to specify anything there, so you can leave the Main class field blank and click Finish.

Give it a try !

Comment: I've tried this before.  When I launch the JAR file I get the error message: Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from \...\fileName.jar

Comment: Note that an applet cannot be launched by double-clicking it.  It needs to be embedded in HTML.